# Android MediaPlayer crashes after exactly 40 initializations

Tags: java, android

**System**
Lenovo Tablet M10 Plus 3rd Generation
RAM: 3GB
ROM: 32GB
CPU: MediaTek G80,2x A75, 2.0GHz + 6x A55 1.8GHz
API Level: 33

**Problem:**
My activity starts playing an audio file as soon as it loads.
There are controls on that activity that start other activities regardless if a song is playing.
Leaving and returning to this activity plays the audio file exactly 40 times before failing to start with error:
MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -19)
MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)

**Code**

```
    private void setupMediaPlayer() throws IOException {
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build());
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(mTrack));
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (isSameTrack)
                    currentTempo = mBundle.getInt("previousTempo");
                setTempo(currentTempo);
                setVolume(currentVolume);
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mp.start();
            }
        }
        );


    public void changeSectionButton(View view) {
        closeMediaPlayer();
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(PlaySong.this, PickExercise.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("Dictionary", DictionaryManager.toString(mDictionary));
        mSection = (mSection.equals("Barre")) ? "Center" : "Barre";
        mIntent.putExtra("Section", mSection);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }



    private void closeMediaPlayer(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;
    }
```

I am expecting the activity to start and start playing the audio file an indefinite number of times I arrive at the activity

Comment: Why are you creating more than 1?  MediaPlayer is meant to be reused.  Issue a reset() and move on to the next thing you want to play.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am calling setupMediaPlayer() in the onCreate method of the activity. What happens to the activity class that I am in when changeSectionButton() is called? Does it garbage collected? If not how do I call this instance of the class from another activity? If MediaPlayer is meant to be reused, how to I reference it between activities?

Comment: If you want it to be usable in multiple Activities (for example if its playing music while you're in any page of the app), you put it in a bound service which you can use to send commands to it.